# would the width of simulation 95% confidence interval for k<2 proportion in multinomial sample be narow, wide or same comparing indvidual CI?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, sampling

*a categorical response variable can take on K different values.
Apparently a narrow confidence interval implies that there is a smaller chance of obtaining an observation within that interval, therefore, our accuracy is higher. Also a 95% confidence interval is narrower than a 99% confidence interval which is wider.*

**Would this be a correct explination if not what would be the best reason?**

Answer (score 0):

*Sort of.*

Recall that CI are to estimate the real mean of a population, based on some sample data from that population.

It is true that a 95% CI would be smaller (narrower) than a 99% one.

It is directly tied to your alpha value (significance level), so an alpha of 5% would mean that you run a *theoretical* 5% risk that your CI does not contain the actual/real mean value.

Thus, if we want to minimize this risk, thus increasing significance, we could set alpha to 1%, and the CI would become a (100-alpha)% CI. And just like you observed, this 99% interval is much larger, because me want a lower risk, so it is larger to cover a much more broader range of values. - making it less likely that we miss the real mean.

Like I mentioned, this risk is theoretical and is pretty much: "What is the chance that the data (and our CI we created from it) just happened to be so incorrect (by sheer chance) that the real mean value is outside of our CI?"

So, it is only a probability calculation based on how much data you had, and how widely spread it was.

And **that's** why the wideness/narrowness differs between them. A 95% CI indicates that you have selected your significance level (alpha) to be 5%.